# ngettext doesn't work in the native langage (PHP)

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, printf, gettext

in PHP, ngettext doesn't work in the native langage.

If I code :

```
printf( ngettext( '%d article avalaible', '%d articles avalaible', 0), 0);
```

It will return in English (native langage) :

> 0 article**s** avalaible

But return the correct form in French (translated with poedit):

> 0 article disponible

I don't understand why....

Comment: I'm not familiar with ngettext() but the plural form _"0 article**s** available"_ is the correct phrase in English.

Comment: OMG you're right after quick research it seems there is only in french that you don't have to put a 's' if you have a 0... If I use a 1 instead of 0 in english ngettext remove the 's'.
Thanks you everything is OK now ;)

Comment: Romain... please add solution to a new (own)answer. That is allowed to do so. Do not edit your question to fix the problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK there is no problem, just my mistake.

In French when we have a 0, we don't have to put the word in plural. 
In English, with zero items, we have to put items in plural.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've answered your own question, but I thought I'd add some technical Gettext info.

The MO file dictates the plural rules, and your example is correct for French, according to the Unicode standard.

Unicode's CLDR plural rules **tend** to be observed by software that edits PO and compiles MO files.  [e.g. for French](https://unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#fr) shows that for cardinal plurals (those we use for quantities) the "one" form is for integers `0` and `1` only.

You will see in your French PO and MO files that the `Plural-Forms` header has an equation in terms of `n` (being the quantity). It will likely be `(n > 1)` or a similar equation that results in the offset `1` (meaning `msgstr[1]`) when n (passed into ngettext ) is anything greater than 1.

If you were to change this header to say `(n != 1)` you would get plurals like English and German where "one" is only ever `1`.

It's an imperfect system, because in English we might like to say "No articles available" for zero. But Gettext only supports two forms in the source language. Also these rules must apply to the entire file, meaning that individual strings can't have their own rules.

If complex plurals are important in your application I might recommend a system that uses more expressive plural logic, such as [Symfony's implementation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#explicit-interval-pluralization).